# PHP: Session not working correctly in live server?

Tags: php, session

My sessions are working correctly in my localhost. But when I use it in live server it needs to be logged out first for login. For example, when I have to login I will first log out then log in otherwise it shows a blank page. I don't know why this is happening.
 **This is my Login page**

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && $_SESSION['login']=="true") {
    header("location:userOwnProfile.php");
    exit();
}
else
{

?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>Register</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="register.css">
            <script src="jquery-1.12.2.min.js"></script>
            <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        </head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar nav-top navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="link one"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="link">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Blog</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="link"><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
                    <li class="link"><a href="#">Terms & Cond</a></li>
                    <li class="link"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="one"><a href="#">Facebook Login</a></li>
                    <li class="one"><a href="#">Login</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>


    <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 si">

        <h3 class="center"><u>MEMBERS LOG IN</u></h3>
<BR>

        <form action="Login.php" method="post">


            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="email">Email:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <input type="email" name="user_email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" required>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="pwd">Password:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <input type="password" name="user_password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 ">

                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-9 col-sm-9 col-md-9 ">
                    <a href="#"><h4>Forgot Password</h4></a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 ">

                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-9 col-sm-9 col-md-9 ">
                    <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 ">

                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-9 col-sm-9 col-md-9 ">
                    <!--<input  class="btn btn-lg btn-danger">-->
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" name="submit" value="Login">
                </div>
            </div>





        </form>
    </div>
    <?php
    include("db.php");
    /*if(isset($_POST['Go'])) {    SIGNUP
        $user_name = $_POST['user_name'];
        $user_password = $_POST['user_password'];
        $user_email = $_POST['user_email'];
        echo $user_name . "<br>";
        echo $user_email . "<br>";
        echo $user_password . "<br>";
        $sql = "INSERT INTO user(user_name,user_email,user_password) VALUE ('$user_name','$user_email','$user_password')";
        if(mysqli_query($conn,$sql))
        {
            echo "stored";
            header("location:http://localhost/window.php");
        }
        else
        {
          die(mysqli_error($sql));
        }
    }*/


    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $user_email = $_POST['user_email'];//real_escape_string
        //echo $user_email;

        $user_password = $_POST['user_password'];
        $login_query="SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_email='$user_email' AND user_password='$user_password'";
        $run=mysqli_query($conn,$login_query) or die($conn);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($run)>0)

        {
            $res = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_email='$user_email'");

            while ($record = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {

                $_SESSION['Name'] = $record['user_name'];
                //$_SESSION['user_lname'] = $record['user_lname'];
                //$_SESSION['user_status'] = $record['user_status'];
                $_SESSION['user_email'] = $record['user_email'];
                $_SESSION['user_id'] = $record['user_id'];
                $_SESSION['login'] = "true";

            }



            //echo $_SESSION['user_fname'] . $_SESSION['user_lname'];
            //echo "NAME: " .  $_SESSION['Name'];

           echo '<script>window.location="userOwnProfile.php"</script>';

                    }
        else
            echo "<p style='color: red; margin-top: -28px;'>User name or password incorrect</p>";
    }

  ?>


    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="jumbotron bottom">

            <div class="row bott">
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 low">
                    <h3>Blog Feeds</h3>

                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 low">
                    <h3>Testimony</h3>

                    <h5>

                    </h5>

                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 low">
                    <h3>Facebook Like Box</h3>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
</div>






</body>
</html></title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
<?php } ?>
```

**This is the page which I will be redirected when I login**

```
    <?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['login'])) {
header("location:Login.php");
}
else {
    $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    $user_email = $_SESSION['user_email'];
    include("db.php");

    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>User's Own Profile</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome-4.5.0/css/font-awesome.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
        <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/newCustom.js"></script>


    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="container">
        <?php
            include 'customNav.php'
        ?>

    <!--Navbar-->


    <div class="row topsecond">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h3 class="heading">Ads</h3>
        </div>
    </div>

        <!--Ads-->


<!--        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8">
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-5">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">My Profile</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-5">
                    <a type="button" href="Search.php" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Find People</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-5">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Message List</button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-5">
                    <a href="#">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">New Likes</button>
                    </a></div>
                </a>

                <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-5">
                    <form>
                    <button type="button" class="g btn btn-lg btn-primary" ><span id="message">  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-inbox"></span> </span>
                    </button>
                        <form>

                </div>


            </div>


        </div>

        -->




        <!--Links-->


        <div class="col-lg-8 left">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="row ">
                    <?php
                    $photo = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_id='$user_id'");

                    while ($recordPhoto = mysqli_fetch_array($photo)) {

                    if ($recordPhoto == FALSE) {
                        die(mysqli_error("error message for the user"));

                    }
                    ?>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 img">

                        <img class="center-block img-rounded" src="<?php echo "../shadi/images/" . $recordPhoto['user_photo1'] ?>"
                             alt=""
                             width="80%" height="220px">
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 img">

                        <img class="center-block img-rounded" src="../shadi/images/team-hire.jpg" alt="" width="80%" height="220px">
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 img">
                        <img class="center-block img-rounded" src="../shadi/images/team-hire.jpg" alt="" width="80%" height="220px">
                        <?php
                        }
                        ?>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="row upload">
                    <!--<div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-5 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-5 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="form">
                            <h4 for="exampleInputFile">File input</h4>
                           <input type="file" id="exampleInputFile">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>-->
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-5 col-xs-12">
                        <a href="userOwnProfileSetting.php">
                            <div class="btn btn-lg btn-info edit">
                                Edit Profile
                            </div>
                    </div>
                    </a>

                </div>
            </div>
            <?php
            $res = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_id=$user_id");

            while ($record = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {

            if ($record == FALSE) {
                die(mysqli_error("error message for the user"));

            }
            ?>
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12">
                <div class="row">
                    <h3 class="heading col-sm-4"><u>Profile Settings</u></h3>

                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <h3><u><?php echo $record['user_name']; ?></u></h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="">
                    <div class="row">
                        <h4 class="col-sm-4">Gender :</h4>

                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <h5><?php echo $record['user_gender']; ?></h5>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="">
                    <div class="row">
                        <h4 class=" col-sm-4">Date of Birth :</h4>

                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <h5><?php echo $record['user_dob']; ?></h5>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="">
                    <div class="row">
                        <h4 class=" col-sm-4">Age :</h4>

                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <h5>31 years</h5>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="">
                    <div class="row">
                        <h4 class=" col-sm-4">Height :</h4>

                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <h5><?php echo $record['user_height']; ?></h5>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="">
                    <div class="row">
                        <h4 class=" col-sm-4">Weight :</h4>

                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <h5><?php echo $record['user_weight']; ?></h5>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="">
                    <div class="row">
                        <h4 class=" col-sm-4">Race :</h4>

                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <h5><?php echo $record['user_race']; ?></h5>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="">
                    <div class="row">
                        <h4 class=" col-sm-4">Religion :</h4>

                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <h5><?php echo $record['user_religion']; ?></h5>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>

                <div class="">
                    <div class="row">
                        <h4 class=" col-sm-4">Country :</h4>

                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <h5> <?php echo $record['user_country']; ?> </h5>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="">
                    <div class="row">
                        <h4 class=" col-sm-4">State Origin :</h4>

                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <h5> <?php echo $record['user_stateOfOrigin']; ?>
                            </h5></div>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="">
                    <div class="row">
                        <h4 class=" col-sm-4">State Living :</h4>

                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <h5> <?php echo $record['user_stateLiving']; ?></h5>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="">
                    <div class="row">
                        <h4 class=" col-sm-4">Marital Stauts :</h4>

                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <h5><?php echo $record['user_maritalStatus']; ?></h5>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="">
                    <div class="row">
                        <h4 class=" col-sm-4">Career :</h4>

                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <h5><?php echo $record['user_career']; ?></h5>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="">
                    <div class="row">
                        <h4 class=" col-sm-4">Educational Level :</h4>

                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <h5><?php echo $record['user_educationLevel']; ?></h5>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>

                <div class="">
                    <div class="row">
                        <h4 class="col-sm-4">Relations for</h4>

                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <h5><?php echo $record['user_relationshipfor']; ?></h5>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="">
                    <div class="row">
                        <h4 class="col-sm-4">Plygamy :</h4>

                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <h5><?php echo $record['user_polygamy']; ?></h5>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="">
                    <div class="row">
                        <h4 class="col-sm-4">Interest :</h4>

                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <h5><?php echo $record['user_interest']; ?></h5>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="">
                    <div class="row">
                        <h4 class="col-sm-4">Smoking :</h4>

                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <h5><?php echo $record['user_smokingVape']; ?></h5>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <h4 class=" col-sm-4">Self Summary : <br>
                    </h4>

                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <h5><?php echo $record['user_selfSummary']; ?></h5>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>


                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">

                    </div>
                    <!--<div class="col-sm-8">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-warning">Submit</button>
                    </div>-->
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

        <!--form done-->


        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <div class="row right">
                <h2>Ads</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="row yes">
                <h2 class="status"><u>Status</u></h2>
                <h4 class="gly"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span><?php echo $record['user_Likes'] . " Likes"; ?></h4>


                <h4 class="gly"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Normal Member</h4>
                <h4 class="gly"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign"></span> Offline</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="row yes">
                <h3 class="status"><u>I'm looking for</u></h3>

                <p class="nigga"> <?php echo $record['user_lookingFor']; ?> :D</p>
            </div>

            <div class="row yes">
                <h3 class="status"><u>Facebook Like Box</u></h3>
            </div>
        </div>


        <?php
        }
        ?>





    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
    <?php
}
?>
```

**Code for logout**

```
<?php
session_start();
unset($_SESSION['Name']);
unset($_SESSION['user_email']);
unset($_SESSION['user_id']);
unset($_SESSION['login']);
header("location:index.php");

session_destroy();
exit();
?>
```

I want to know why this is happening in live server. Why I need to log out first to get myself logged in.

Comment: Please post your logout script

Comment: i also had same issue i put include("db.php"); before session_start();

Comment: @NeelIon: I have posted the code for logout

Comment: @AbhijitJagtap: It works fine in my localhost. Problem in my server

Comment: When you are going to your login page first time, is it showing the login form?

Comment: After one day it automatically logs out.. But when I have to login it requires logout first manually

Comment: how do you keep users login for 1 day? you are not using any cookie for remembering user?

Comment: @NeelIon But my problem is that Why do I need to logout first?

Comment: To solve yur problem i need to now how do you keep users logged in for 1 day. since you need to logout again after 1 day.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122333/discussion-between-neel-ion-and-imran-hasan).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your userOwnProfile.php script sending output before sending header.
There are some spaces before `<?php` tag. Remove those spaces.
Hope this will help

Comment: Do I need encoding configuration in the editor (phpStorm) too?

Comment: if it is with BOM then yes, make it utf-8 without BOM.